# Quick Java question about private static final keywords for fields

Tags: java, static, private, final

I'm declaring a field:

```
private static final String filename = "filename.txt";
```

First, does the order of `private static final` matter? If not, is there a standard accepted sequence or convention?

Second, the `filename` in my application is fixed. Is this the best was to store its value?

Comment: static final is preferred according to JLS!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) with Eclipse, which results in a warning if the declaration is in a different order to the one you've specified, citing the Java Language Specification (JLS).  For example,

```
private final static String filename = "filename.txt";
```

results in

```
'static' modifier out of order with the JLS suggestions.
```

They have [this page](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html) which lists the order they expect, though following the links on that page through to the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html) I can't see anything to back up their assertion of a suggested order.

Having said that, the order they suggest seems to correspond to the order in most of the code I've seen, so it seems as good a convention as any to adopt.

Comment: See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809411/1587329) for the docs and a link to them.

Comment: Yeah should be private static final String

Answer (score 23):

1. No.  But that is the sequence I usually see used.
2. It's a reasonable choice, but some would prefer a configuration file, either [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) or another file format (e.g. XML).  That way, you can change the filename without recompiling.

Comment: How would you get the file name of the configuration file? :)

Comment: @Tom, that's a valid point.  Of course, real applications will have many such constants, all of which can be in a single properties file.

Answer (score 15):

It's common in Java to give constants (`static final` values) an all-uppercase name, so I would write:

```
private static final String FILENAME = "filename.txt";
```

See also [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). (Those are Sun's code conventions that the majority of Java programmers use).

Comment: That link no longer goes anywhere useful. :-(

Comment: @JimL. fixed the link, although Oracle's page says that this document is "for archive purposes only".

Answer (score 11):

The most accepted order of these keywords is `private static final`. Also you can remember the order of these keywords using **PSF** pattern that:

> **P** => private / public / protected
>   **S** => static / abstract / ...
>   **F** => final

Comment: `PSF` mnemonic is the best! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.3.1

8.3.1 Field Modifiers

FieldModifiers:
  FieldModifier
  FieldModifiers FieldModifier

FieldModifier: one of
  Annotation public protected private
  static final transient volatile

...

If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is *customary*, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for FieldModifier.

Answer (score 4):

To complete the nice answer [by @Hobo above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832504/1587329) by a [current link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)

> #### 8.1.1. Class Modifiers
>
> A class declaration may include class modifiers.
>
> ```
>      ClassModifier:
>          (one of) 
>          Annotation public protected private 
>          abstract static final strictfp
> ```

[...]

> If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class
> declaration, then it is customary, though not required, that they
> appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production
> for ClassModifier.

Answer (score 3):

1. The order doesn't matter, but you can always play around with it - there's only 6 possibilities to test.
2. I'm not aware of any convention, though I put the visibility modifier first (public/private/protected) so you can eyeball it and it lines up.
3. If it's fixed then you can do that, but I always think something is a constant only to discover later (during testing, for example) that I want to pass it in.  An argument on the command line or a properties file works for that case, and is a minimum of effort to set up.