# Does the order of keywords in variable definition matter?

Tags: java, final, static-variables, class-variables

Is there any difference between the order:

```
public static final String = "something";
```

or

```
public final static String = "something";
```

?

Comment: Nope. As long as it compiles.

Comment: IMHO, Following code convention order improves readability, nothing else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, although the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) recommends that you use the first ordering:

> ```
> FieldModifiers:
>   FieldModifier
>   FieldModifiers FieldModifier
>
> FieldModifier: one of
>   Annotation public protected private
>   static final transient volatile
> ```
>
> ...
>   If two or more (distinct) field
>   modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, it is customary, though
>   not required, that they appear in the
>   order consistent with that shown above
>   in the production for FieldModifier.

Comment: Thanks, will follow the convention that recommends to use the first ordering. :)

Answer (score 7):

No - there is no difference betweeen the two.

From section 8.3.1 of the Java 2 Language Specification:

> "If two or more (distinct) field
>   modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, it is customary, though
>   not required, that they appear in the
>   order consistent with that shown above
>   in the production for FieldModifier."

Comment: I agree, as far as I know, there is no difference.  However, there are code conventions that are recommended by java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: @pgras you seem to be correct.  My bad.  There is this post already that discusses the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832126/quick-java-question-about-private-static-final-keywords-for-fields

Answer (score 0):

No. Pick one and follow that naming convention consistently